# CSS Grid inside parent with absolute positioning issue

Tags: html, css, css-position, css-grid

I am trying to achieve as many columns as it can fit in a row of a grid using `auto-fill`.
This is how the code works correctly.

```css
.grid-container {
  border: solid 1px green;
  padding: 3px;
  min-width: 400px;
  max-width: 900px;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 900px;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(294px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 12px;
}

.item {
  border: solid 1px red;
  min-height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="drawer">
  <div class="grid-container"> 
   <div class="grid">
     <div class="item">This is grid item</div>
     <div class="item">This is grid item</div>
     <div class="item">This is grid item</div>
     <div class="item">This is grid item</div>
     <div class="item">This is grid item</div>
     <div class="item">This is grid item</div>
     <div class="item">This is grid item</div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

But I need the container `drawer` to have absolute positioning. If I set it to absolute positioning, the grid autofill stops working and the grid creates just one column without trying to fit more columns.

```css
.grid-container {
  border: solid 1px green;
  padding: 3px;
  min-width: 400px;
  max-width: 900px;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 900px;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(294px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 12px;
}

.item {
  border: solid 1px red;
  min-height: 80px;
}

.drawer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="drawer">
  <div class="grid-container"> 
   <div class="grid">
     <div class="item">This is grid item</div>
     <div class="item">This is grid item</div>
     <div class="item">This is grid item</div>
     <div class="item">This is grid item</div>
     <div class="item">This is grid item</div>
     <div class="item">This is grid item</div>
     <div class="item">This is grid item</div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why is this happening and how to make the grid work correctly?

Answer (score 0):

The `.drawer` element has no definite width set.

If you add `right: 0` or `width: <anything>` it will get a width and the grid has a horizontal dimension context to work with.

In your example above the width of the `.grid` is determined by the `min-width` of the `.grid-container` element

```css
body {
  /* needed fot this presentation on SE */
  /* unclear of needed IRE */
  position: relative;
}
.drawer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.grid-container {
  border: solid 1px green;
  padding: 3px;
  min-width: 400px;
  max-width: 900px;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 900px;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(294px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 12px;
}

.item {
  border: solid 1px red;
  min-height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="drawer">
  <div class="grid-container"> 
   <div class="grid">
     <div class="item">This is grid item</div>
     <div class="item">This is grid item</div>
     <div class="item">This is grid item</div>
     <div class="item">This is grid item</div>
     <div class="item">This is grid item</div>
     <div class="item">This is grid item</div>
     <div class="item">This is grid item</div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to make it so that the `drawer` container does not have a specific width, only max width.

Comment: @Interloper I added `max-width` to `.drawer`

Comment: also why do set `height` if you dont use `overflow-y: auto` as well?

Comment: I made some additional changes. `body` has now `position: relative`, so that `.drawer` does not use full width including scroll bars. I also removed `height` and `bottom` like s3c suggested

Comment: @yunzen in your answer you set width: 900px for `drawer`. Width should not be specified explicitly in my case.

Comment: I removed the `width` in `.drawer`. Only `max-width: 100%` remains

Comment: max-width can also be removed here. left/right set to 0 are enough

Comment: @yunzen Setting a value for `right` is equivalent to setting a value for `width`. I need `drawer` not to take up all the available width, unless it is required for the placement of the children.